# aes-256-gcm decryption from PHP to Golang

Tags: php, go, encryption, openssl

I have an encryption function that I use in PHP

```
function Encrypt(?string $Content, string $Key): string {
    return openssl_encrypt($Content, 'aes-256-gcm', $Key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV = random_bytes(16), $Tag, '', 16) . $IV . $Tag;
}
```

Paired with a decryption function

```
function Decrypt(?string $Ciphertext, string $Key): ?string {
    if (strlen($Ciphertext) < 32)
        return null;

    $Content = substr($Ciphertext, 0, -32);
    $IV = substr($Ciphertext, -32, -16);
    $Tag = substr($Ciphertext, -16);

    try {
        return openssl_decrypt($Content, 'aes-256-gcm', $Key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV, $Tag);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I store data encrypted from the encryption function into my db, and now I'm trying to decrypt those same values in Go, but I'm getting `cipher: message authentication failed` and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
c := []byte(`encrypted bytes of sorts`) // the bytes from the db

content := c[:len(c)-32]
iv := c[len(c)-32 : len(c)-16]
tag := c[len(c)-16:]

block, err := aes.NewCipher(key[:32])
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCMWithNonceSize(block, 16)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

fmt.Println(aesgcm.NonceSize(), aesgcm.Overhead()) // making sure iv and tag are both 16 bytes

plaintext, err := aesgcm.Open(nil, iv, append(content, tag...), nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

It's worth noting that the key I'm using isn't 32 bytes (it's way bigger), as I didn't know the key needed/should be 32 bytes, so I'm not entirely sure what PHP is doing with it (as in truncating it to 32 vs hashing it with something having 32 bytes of output vs some other thing).

Looking at the `Open` function from the Go source, it looks like the tag should be the last "tag size" bytes of the text, so that's why I'm appending the tag to the ciphertext after parsing the pieces.

```
// copied from C:\Go\src\crypto\cipher\gcm.go, Go version 1.11
func (g *gcm) Open(dst, nonce, ciphertext, data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(nonce) != g.nonceSize {
        panic("cipher: incorrect nonce length given to GCM")
    }

    if len(ciphertext) < gcmTagSize {
        return nil, errOpen
    }
    if uint64(len(ciphertext)) > ((1<<32)-2)*uint64(g.cipher.BlockSize())+gcmTagSize {
        return nil, errOpen
    }

    tag := ciphertext[len(ciphertext)-gcmTagSize:]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[:len(ciphertext)-gcmTagSize]

    var counter, tagMask [gcmBlockSize]byte
    g.deriveCounter(&counter, nonce)

    g.cipher.Encrypt(tagMask[:], counter[:])
    gcmInc32(&counter)

    var expectedTag [gcmTagSize]byte
    g.auth(expectedTag[:], ciphertext, data, &tagMask)

    ret, out := sliceForAppend(dst, len(ciphertext))

    if subtle.ConstantTimeCompare(expectedTag[:], tag) != 1 {
        // The AESNI code decrypts and authenticates concurrently, and
        // so overwrites dst in the event of a tag mismatch. That
        // behavior is mimicked here in order to be consistent across
        // platforms.
        for i := range out {
            out[i] = 0
        }
        return nil, errOpen
    }

    g.counterCrypt(out, ciphertext, &counter)

    return ret, nil
}
```

---

PHP example using the functions above

```
$Key = 'outspoken outburst treading cramp cringing';

echo bin2hex($Enc = Encrypt('yeet', $Key)), '<br>'; // 924b3ba418f49edc1757f3fe88adcaa7ec4c1e7d15811fd0b712b0b091433073f6a38d7b
var_export(Decrypt($Enc, $Key)); // 'yeet'
```

Go

```
c, err := hex.DecodeString(`924b3ba418f49edc1757f3fe88adcaa7ec4c1e7d15811fd0b712b0b091433073f6a38d7b`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
key := []byte(`outspoken outburst treading cramp cringing`)

content := c[:len(c)-32]
iv := c[len(c)-32 : len(c)-16]
tag := c[len(c)-16:]

block, err := aes.NewCipher(key[:32])
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCMWithNonceSize(block, 16)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

ciphertext := append(content, tag...) // or `ciphertext := content`, same error

plaintext, err := aesgcm.Open(nil, iv, ciphertext, nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error()) // panic: cipher: message authentication failed
}
```

Comment: this one will help u - https://gist.github.com/cannium/c167a19030f2a3c6adbb5a5174bea3ff

Comment: @myxaxa Lol that's literally what I have above, in fact, it's where I got my example from

Comment: I know ^_^ but I wanted to point u on the key and the ciphertext length

Comment: @rustyx I've added a literal example of actual code that doesn't work as I'm expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an encrypted message looks like `IV+ciphertext+tag`, not `ciphertext+IV+tag`. When one deviates from the convention one runs into all kinds of issues :-)

Have you seen what happens to the `iv` *slice* after the call `append(ciphertext, tag...)`?
You essentially overwrite the `iv` with the `tag`:

```
Before:
924b3ba4 18f49edc1757f3fe88adcaa7ec4c1e7d 15811fd0b712b0b091433073f6a38d7b
After:
924b3ba4 15811fd0b712b0b091433073f6a38d7b 15811fd0b712b0b091433073f6a38d7b
```

As a quick fix, make a copy of the `iv` before calling `append()`:

```
iv := make([]byte, 16)
copy(iv, c[len(c)-32 : len(c)-16])
```

More info on slices can be found [here](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Comment: I assure you I didn't write the entirety of the PHP implementation myself :) But I'll be damned, it totally works now. I'll admit I was quite under the assumption that `append` was returning a new slice pointing to a new array, but I guess it only does that if it needs to grow the array, and in this case, it wouldn't need to. Thank you for your amazing help :)!